# SQL - Problems with matching data when getting information from 2 tables `duplicant'

Tags: sql

I want to make a query where i can monitor the following :

The time between when someone in our department sends a task to someone and when our department receives a message back.

Every task can separated into messages, most of them have have 2 (send and received) others have more like 4+ (2x send and 2x received).
I have the send and received messages in a diffrent temp table called; TaskTo, TaskBack. All messages have an timestamp. They also have an description, which in this case dosn't matter.

The issue starts when i have 4 or more messages within 1 task:

```
Tables:
Table = #TaskTo 
╔════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ ID     ║ Time   ║ Desc ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════╣
║      1 ║ 14:25  ║ x    ║
║      2 ║ 16:00  ║ x    ║
║      2 ║ 11:00  ║ x    ║
║      3 ║ 15:02  ║ x    ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════╝

Table = #TaskBack
╔════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ ID     ║ Time   ║ Desc ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════╣
║      1 ║ 14:30  ║ x    ║
║      2 ║ 19:00  ║ x    ║
║      2 ║ 12:01  ║ x    ║
║      3 ║ 17:20  ║ x    ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

=================================

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT                         
to.ID, 
to.time as time1,
Bk.time as time2, 
DATEDIFF (HOUR, to.EndTask,Bk.EndTask) as diff

FROM #TaskTo as to LEFT JOIN #TaskBack as Bk on to.TicketNumber = Bk.Ticketnumber
ORDER BY to.ID
```

=================================

This is what i get as an result :

```
╔════════╦════════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID     ║ Time1  ║ time2║ diff ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════╬══════╣
║      1 ║ 14:25  ║ 14:30║0     ║
║      2 ║ 16:00  ║ 19:00║3     ║
║      2 ║ 16:00  ║ 12:01║20    ║
║      2 ║ 11:00  ║ 19:00║8     ║
║      2 ║ 11:00  ║ 12:01║1     ║
║      3 ║ 15:02  ║ 17:20║2     ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════╩══════╝
```

The issue hereby is that the data is `Duplicant`:

```
║      2 ║ 16:00  ║ 19:00║3     ║
║      2 ║ 16:00  ║ 12:01║20    ║
║      2 ║ 11:00  ║ 19:00║8     ║
║      2 ║ 11:00  ║ 12:01║1     ║
```

The dream scenario is :

```
║      2 ║ 16:00  ║ 19:00║3     ║
║      2 ║ 11:00  ║ 12:01║1     ║
```

Can anyone explain what i did incorrect ? :)

Thank you for your time.

With kind regards,
M.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in transaction IDs? 
It is the only reason why you get duplicates in output. Every ticket should have unique ID and your solution will work perfectly

Comment: Is it Id or TicketNumber ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Could one toTask don't have a taskBack?

Comment: @Qxg, Yes, after i talked to my supervisor we only show Solved Tasks, so every task should have a message to and a message back.

Comment: @Mack It worked like a train, as mentioned above the business rule that we only monitor solved tasks really helps a lot, else the Time2 is shifting with time1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems that I can see straight away:

- There is no uniqueness in the tables you are showing us, so of course
  you will end up with duplicates.
- Your query doesn't match your table diagrams(you don't mention
  TicketNumber anywhere in the diagrams.)
- You are using [sql reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) as table aliases and fieldnames.

I have created a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d482/4), perhaps you could expand it so that it matches your situation more closely, the include the revised sql fiddle in your question...

Here is a revised [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d482/2).

Here is the code example:

```
SELECT  tto.ID, 
        tto.[time] as time1,
        tbk.[time] as time2, 
        DATEDIFF (HOUR, tto.[time],tbk.[time]) as diff
FROM       (SELECT  ID,
                    [Time],
                    Descr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                    ID,
                    [Time]) AS rowId
            FROM TaskTo) tto
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   ID,
                    [Time],
                    Descr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                    ID,
                    [Time]) AS rowId
            FROM TaskBack
            ) AS tbk
    ON tto.rowid = tbk.rowid
```

Results:

```
ID  TIME1               TIME2               DIFF
1   14:25:00.0000000    14:30:00.0000000    0
2   11:00:00.0000000    12:01:00.0000000    1
2   16:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000    3
3   15:02:00.0000000    17:20:00.0000000    2
```

Caveat, these results are based on a very small data sample.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using T-SQL syntax for reserved keyword here. Please modify to others if you're not using SQL Server.

```
SELECT
[to].ID, 
[to].[time] as time1,
[Bk].[time] as time2, 
DATEDIFF (HOUR, [to].EndTask,[Bk].EndTask) as diff
FROM 
(
    SELECT Id, [Time], [Desc],
    LEAD([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Time]) AS NextTime
    FROM #TaskTo
) AS [To]
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Id, [Time], [Desc],
    FROM #TaskBack
) AS Bk on [to].Id = Bk.Id AND [to].[Time] < [bk].[Time] AND ([to].NextTime > [bk].Time OR [to].NextTime IS NULL)
ORDER BY [to].ID
```

Comment: I am getting the following error : LEAD is not a recognized built-in function name, i did some google work and found about LAG and LEAD functionality. I shall try some new stuff in the hope that it works and i keep you guys informed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mikamura LEAD was only introduced in SQL 2012 so if you are using an older version it won't be available to you.  See my modified answer above for one possible solution avoiding LEAD.